# Using a custom function that returns items Selected from a list box

Tags: ms-access, vba

Windows 7, ACCESS 10
Based on a previous answer from HansUp, I created the following function that returns the values selected in a listbox:

```
Public Function listboxSel(ByVal listName As String) As Integer
MsgBox Nz(Me.Controls(listName).Value, "Null")
End Function
```

I call the function from the LostFocus event of the Listbox:

```
 Dim cageHrsHold As Integer
 cageHrsHold = listboxSel(cageHrs)
```

I left the MsgBox in the function just to see if it executed. That line, the MsgBox line in the function, bombs with "Anbiguous name detected:listboxSel".

jpl

Comment: I used the same listboxLB name in your suggestion that was in my aborted attempt, so there were two functions with the same name. Will test in the AM.  Will advise, and many things for your thorough answers.

Comment: Just tested it. On the line MsgBox Nz(Me.Controls(listName).Value, "Null") I got "Invalid use of Me keyword".  I deleted the Me. and got "Sub or function not defined: MsgBox Nz(Controls(listName).Value, "Null")

Comment: cageHrs is the name of a listbox control that drops down the hours of the day. And I added the quite to listboxSel("cageHrs").  Still got "Sub or function not defined"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113148/discussion-between-user3216034-and-hansup).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113189/discussion-between-jpl458-and-hansup).